# How to enable disk cache again after enabling iSCSI in Windows Server 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2012, cache, iscsi

I create an iSCSI Virtual Disk and a corresponding target. This enables the cache bypass flag on the volume. After I remove the iSCSI disk, the flag doesn't get reset.

Anyone can help me to reset this flag without recreating the volume? Would be awesome even if we can enable it for the running iSCSI disk...

In 2012 R2 the flag only gets set when the Initiator actually asks for it:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn305893.aspx